# Can not understand the ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I don't understand why my R code give me this error:

> `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(   sliderInput(inputId = "num", 
           label = "Choose a number", 
           value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),   plotOutput("ggplot") )

server <- function(input, output) {   output$ggplot <- renderPlot({
 ggplot(data=rnorm(input$num), aes(input$num)) + geom_histogram()   }) }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `ggplot` should be a data frame. You have supplied the output of `rnorm()`, which is a vector. That's the first problem.

The second is that `aes()` should refer to a column name in the supplied data frame.

I would create a data frame first using `input$num`. Something like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  data_df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(as.numeric(input$num)))
  output$ggplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = data_df, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram()

  })
}
```